# What to be careful of when replacing the backlight fuse in a MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, motherboard

I blew my MacBook air's backlight fuse.

I saw some videos on YouTube explaining how to remove blown fuse with a soldering iron, and soldering a new one back on. However, these videos don't mention the risks, and what one should be careful of when doing that.

What are the risks ? What should one pay extra attention to ?

Comment: This might be better for a chat forum / fixit / chat room. We can't really know your skill level. there's no risk if you are trained, have parts and can afford to replace a part if you break things. Even seasoned, trained technicians sometimes break things. Consider showing more of your research or editing the post to describe your specific question instead of "hey everyone - let's discuss repair of this model"

Comment: @bmike thanks for your comment. I think "hey everyone, let's discuss this repair" is a wrong sarcastic caricature of this question. For each repair, there are concrete things that one should pay attention to, regardless of skill. For example, when detaching the bezel from a MacBook Air screen, one can cut through the webcam cable. That's a fact. There are other things of that kind for every repair.

Comment: Hit me up in [chat] or [meta] - no sarcasm employed. Honestly trying to get you to a place where this won't get closed or downvoted. As moderator I see all the closed, questions and was trying to steer this to success. I'm not saying you are wrong, I could have shut down the post with a hold if that was my view.